# How to rectify [PHP Fatal error: Interface 'Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface' not found ] in ratchet

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I'm trying to create a basic websocket chat from a tutorial in YouTube and I'am facing this error in the terminal when I run

```
php bin/server.php
```

> **Fatal error:** Interface 'Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface' not found in /var/www/html/websocket/bin/chat.php on line 6

My code is as follows for chat.php:

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class chat implements MessageComponentInterface
    {
        protected $clients;
        public function __construct()
            {
                $this->clients=new \SplObjectStorage;
            }

        public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
            {
                $this->clients->attach($conn);
            }

        public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
            {
                $this->clients->detach($conn);
            }

        public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $conn,$msg)
            {
                foreach($this->clients as $client){
                    if($client !==$conn){
                        $client->send($msg);
                    }
                }
            }

        public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
            {
                echo "the following error occured: ".$e->getMessage();
                 $conn->close();
            }
    }
```

Code for server.php:

```
<?php
require 'chat.php';
require __DIR__ .'/vendor/autoload.php';
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

$server=IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(new WsServer (new chat())) , 8080);
$server->run();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried declaring the `namespace` first and set that, then used the `use`? http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php I don't really use namespace all that much but the manual appears to do the namespace first, then the `use`.

Comment: well did that still not woking.

Comment: You did `namespace Ratchet;`? Did you include the file that contains the `Ratchet` library?

Comment: yes i did, let me show you the code @Rasclatt

Comment: Where is your namespace though? Notice on the 2nd snippit: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world   It says `namespace MyApp;`

Comment: yes it is 'MyApp' only. i'll update the script to avoid confusion

Comment: Put `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` at the top of the page before your `require 'chat.php';` Should load their stuff first before yours.

Comment: @rasclatt now it comes up with a new error and it is as follow: `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class MyApp\chat in /var/www/html/websocket/bin/chat.php on line 6
`

Comment: I think that is because the `require __DIR__ .'/vendor/autoload.php';` file may be autoloading your class first, then you add it manually (remove this line-> `require 'chat.php';`), so it gives you that error. Try not adding your `chat.php` and see if it works.

Comment: now it gives an another error @Rasclatt `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'chat' not found in /var/www/html/websocket/bin/server.php on line 8
`

Comment: Aaaaah! What a pain!  Ok, I am not sure what the "accepted practice" in this is. Let me think on this for a second.

Comment: O wait, look at that page under **Instantiation**. It adds the autoloader in the `MyApp` class....

Comment: Oh wait, I read that wrong. Hmm, let me see what they are doing in that example...one second.

Comment: You put your class into this path/directory? `/src/MyApp/chat.php` The autoloader maybe looking for it there. Sorry, I am not familiar so I am just reading this through as the tutorial says.

Comment: no its actually like websocket/bin/chat.php.

Answer (score 3):

Include the autoload.php file which has all the definitions for autoloading before using the `Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface`.

Include this code snippet just after defining the namespace:

`require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

Answer (score 1):

go to the composer.json and change

```
{
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4"
    }
}
```

to

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyApp\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4"
    }
}
```

and open command promote with administration update the composer like

```
composer update
```

you should have to be on the same folder directory where the composer.json is on