# Interface 'Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, websocket, composer-php, ratchet

This is my controller:

```php
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Homepage extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // Load package path
        $this->load->add_package_path(FCPATH . 'vendor/takielias/codeigniter-websocket');
        $this->load->library('Codeigniter_websocket');
        $this->load->remove_package_path(FCPATH . 'vendor/takielias/codeigniter-websocket');

        // Run server
        $this->codeigniter_websocket->set_callback('auth', array($this, '_auth'));
        $this->codeigniter_websocket->set_callback('event', array($this, '_event'));
        $this->codeigniter_websocket->run();
    }
}
```

This is the full error I'm receieving:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Interface 'Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface' not found

Filename: vendor\takielias\codeigniter-websocket\libraries\Codeigniter_websocket.php

Line Number: 190

Backtrace:

File: application\controllers\youtube.php
Line: 10
Function: library

File: index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

I've got this in `composer.json`:

```js
"require": {
        "takielias/codeigniter-websocket": "^1.0",
        "php": ">=5.3.7"
    },
```

It's already been installed with `composer install`.  So why wouldn't it work?

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378161/how-to-rectify-php-fatal-error-interface-ratchet-messagecomponentinterface-n) are not helpful, and a best answer wasn't chosen so I assume the asker didn't solve his problem with them.

One answer was this:

> Include this code snippet just after defining the namespace:
>
> `require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

But I haven't defined any namespace, so I don't know how this is relevant.

The other answer said to add this to `composer.json`:

```js
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyApp\\": "src"
        }
    },
```

But I have no folder named `MyApp` (I do have a folder `application`) and I don't know what `psr-4` is supposed to mean.  So again, the answers don't seem to be helpful, or assume that I know more than I do.

Comment: Does your application use `autoload.php` after all? Have you checked whether the dumped autoloader in `vendor/composer` is used, and references the given namespace?

Comment: "I haven't defined any namespace, so I don't know how this is relevant." The autoloading is about *all* namespaces, not just yours.